# Modifying a shell script to select another file group

Tags: shell, sh

I needed to run five commands on the shell such as these

```
python program.py command -z file1.zip ... -z file200.zip &
python program.py command -z file201.zip ... -z file400.zip &
python program.py command -z file401.zip ... -z file600.zip &
python program.py command -z file601.zip ... -z file800.zip &
python program.py command -z file801.zip ... -z file1000.zip &
```

To do this, I used the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

launch()
{
    local args="$1"
    cmd="$mycommad $args"
    $cmd
}

folder='../data_folder'
zips1000="$( find $folder -name '*.zip' |head -n 1000 | xargs )"

n=1
args=''
mycommad="python program.py command "

for zip in $zips1000
do
    if [ $n -eq 200 ]
    then
        launch "$args" &
        args=''
        n=1
    continue
    fi

    args="$args -z $zip"
    n="$(( n + 1 ))"
done


wait
```

Now I would like to run

```
python program.py command -z file1001.zip ... -z file1200.zip &
python program.py command -z file1201.zip ... -z file1400.zip &
python program.py command -z file1401.zip ... -z file1600.zip &
python program.py command -z file1601.zip ... -z file1800.zip &
python program.py command -z file1801.zip ... -z file2000.zip &
```

How should I modify the line

```
zips1000="$( find $folder -name '*.zip' |head -n 1000 | xargs )"
```

in order to do so?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your script's [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is `/bin/sh` so I don't see why you tagged this either [tag:bash] or [tag:zsh]. Your question cannot realistically be about both, but if you want help with one of them, please [edit] to clarify which one and what help. For the time being, I have removed both.

Comment: Your actual question seems to be how to select the 1000 next files after the first 1000, which is trivially `head -n 2000 | tail -n 1000`; but your code seems to be quite a lot more complex than it really needs to be.

Comment: But... why not just `xargs`? `run five commands` `head -n 1000`  if you want to run 5 commands, why do you take 1000 files? I do not understand the code.

Comment: See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Just `xargs` doesn't really do anything useful here, but would offer a significantly simpler solution to your problem. In brief, `xargs -n 200 python program.py mycommand` but the requirement to add `-z` before each file name complicates things (though perhaps you could change or wrap `program.py` to remove or work around this requirement?)

Comment: `head -n 2000 | tail -n 1000` That's it! Thank you @tripleee.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to:

```
# Quote folder!
find "$folder" -name '*.zip' |
# Add -z before each argument.
awk '{ print "-z"; print }' |
# Run the process, 5 in parallel
xargs -t -d '\n' -P 5 -n 400 python program.py command
```

Remember to check your code with shellcheck. Quote variable expansions. For storing a command, use *bash arrays*. Simple `| xargs` is odd, but I find that people oddly use it to replace newlines for spaces. If you *want* to replace newlines for spaces, use `paste -sd' '`.

You could get away with `awk` with `find ... -printf "-z\n%p\n"`.